# PowerShell command fails after variable is used

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, user-profile

I'm trying to run a command to gather use profiles with certain requirements, here's my code:

```
#$numberOfDays = 30
#$numberOfDays

$profileStructsToRemove = Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastUseTime -lt $(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-$numberOfDays) } |
    Where-Object {$_.LocalPath.ToUpper() -ne 'C:\USERS\ADMINISTRATOR'} |
    Where-Object {$_.LocalPath.ToUpper() -ne 'C:\USERS\SOME_PROFILE_TO_KEEP'} |
    Where-Object {$_.LocalPath.ToUpper() -ne 'C:\USERS\PUBLIC'}

$profileStructsToRemove #print
```

I use the `$numberOfDays` variable to determine the number of days subtracted from today's date that I want to use as the filter. Right now it's commented out, and the command succeeds, although since `$numberOfDays` isn't defined I assume it's using a null value? I'm not really sure but it works that way...

However, when I assign `$numberOfDays` to 30, it fails to populate the variable `$profileStructsToRemove` with ANYTHING at all. It just utterly fails. I could really use some input on why this is happenening.

1. How is the command working when `$numberOfDays` isn't defined? Is it just a null value, or treating it as 0 for the `AddDays` function?
2. Why is this command failing once `$numberOfDays` is assigned a value?

Comment: `.AddDays()` expects an integer. `$null` when cast as `[int]` is 0. `[int]$null`

Comment: @Birdman: Please see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it's null, which added zero days. This is fine - you can test with:

   ```
   $(Get-Date).Date.AddDays($null)
   ```
2. Are you sure there are profiles that match that data? Check the data when `$numberOfDays` is `null` to confirm.

Comment: I'll try to verify by looking manually at `Get-CimInstance win32_userprofile` data to see the LastUseTime for all profiles, but simply looking in the file explorer there were profiles with 'date modified' values from back in like January 2018, which is far older than 30 days. Maybe the LastUseTime doesn't reflect the modified date in file explorer. I'll have to compare.

Comment: Turns out the profiles weren't matching the data. Somehow, even though there are profiles that haven't been touched in months (multiple users have since left the company) the LastUseTime field is being updated. Multiple profiles had this field updated at the EXACT same time. I'm not sure what could cause this but it's not any user logging on. Currently trying to find alternate solutions...

Answer (score 2):

[gms0ulman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52632581/45375) answers question #1 well (converting `$null` to an `[int]` yields `0`).

As for question #2:

At least on Windows 11 on a non-domain machine:

- for **currently logged-on accounts** (which may include service accounts), **the `.LastUseTime` property seemingly always returns the *current* date and time**
- **unless you run the command *with elevation* (as administrator)**, you **may see *no* values** for *other* users' profiles.

---

For reference, here's the full list of available time stamps:
`LastAttemptedProfileDownloadTime`, `LastAttemptedProfileUploadTime`, `LastBackgroundRegistryUploadTime`, `LastDownloadTime`, `LastUploadTime`, `LastUseTime`.

---

As for how to **optimize the code in your question** in general:

- PowerShell string operators are case-insensitive by default, so there's no need for `.toUpper()`.
- You could combine your multiple `Where-Object` calls into a single one, and you can use
  `-notin` with an array of paths on the RHS, instead of using `-ne` with individual paths.

To put it all together (PSv3+; keeping in mind that comparing against `.LastUsedTime` may be pointless):

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator
$profileStructsToRemove = 
  Get-CimInstance win32_userprofile |
  Where-Object {
    $_.LastUseTime -lt (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-$numberOfDays) -and
      $_.LocalPath -notin 'C:\USERS\ADMINISTRATOR',
                          'C:\USERS\SOME_PROFILE_TO_KEEP',
                          'C:\USERS\PUBLIC'
  }
```

Comment: Your answer is in tune with what'g wrong with this code. So there are profiles that haven't been logged onto in months but the "LastUseTime" is like 1.5 weeks ago. I'm not sure if an update, or something else triggers this. So it turns out the code is okay but that field is being changed somehow.