# Script to delete user profiles over X amount of days old

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, user-profile

I am trying to create a PowerShell script to delete user profiles on Windows computers (domain environment) over X amount of days old. (Probably will make X = 60 days or so) Here's my code:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Program to delete user profiles through Powershell older than 30 days

# User profiles older than today's date - $ of days will be deleted
$numberOfDays = 30

# Number of digits in local path string to just after C:\users\
$pos = 9

# Get all user profiles where the last log on time is older than the current date - $numberOfDays
$profileStructsToRemove = Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile |
    Where-Object {$_.LastUseTime -lt $(Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-$numberOfDays) } |
    Where-Object {$_.LocalPath.ToUpper() -ne 'C:\USERS\ADMINISTRATOR'} |
    Where-Object {$_.LocalPath.ToUpper() -ne 'C:\USERS\PUBLIC'}

foreach ($struct in $profileStructsToRemove)
{
    $userProfileToDelete = $struct.LocalPath.Substring($pos, $struct.LocalPath.Length - $pos)
    Write-Host "Currently deleting profile...$userProfileToDelete..."
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -Filter "localpath='C:\\Users\\$userProfileToDelete'").Delete()
}
```

My script works pretty well, but there's one problem. I used the field `LastUseTime` as the most important part, to only retrieve profiles older than `numberOfdays`. The problem is after inspecting this field, but just running `Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile` alone, I looked at all the `LastUseTime` entries of every profile. Even some profiles from employees who have left the company (not signed onto for months) have `LastUseTime` entries of a week ago. Oddly enough, many of these profiles have the EXACT some LastUseTime, to the minute. Basically, this field seems useless to me. There's something changing this field that is not the user. An update, or something in the system, I'm really not sure.

**What I need:** To find some kind of replacement for `LastUseTime`. I've been able to find the last logon time for accounts on the computer, but only for LOCAL users. In a domain environment, this basically excludes everyone. Then I looked into querying AD accounts (through `AD-User`), but that gives me last logon information for the profiles itself (from what I understand) and not for a certain computer.

I simply cannot find a way to find the last logon, or last use date, of a user on a profile on a specific computer. The `LastUseTime` field has proved to be useless. (Still not sure what changes it)

Comment: You could read event logs on the target machines for logon events. That is only useful if you have data during those periods.

Comment: It's a good question, but it boils down to why the `.LastUsedTime` time stamp doesn't reflect what you expect it to and where to find the information of interest - and there's no reason to replicate the suboptimal code from [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52632465/45375), especially given that you've been told [how to improve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52633783/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 I'm not sure fully what you mean. I posted a new question since the old one had been resolved. I didn't take the time to re-factor the code (with some of your suggestions) because the main goal of this post was finding a replacement, or some sort of work around, to LastUseTime being pointless. Upon finding some sort of resolution to this, I would take the time to re-factor the code with your suggestions. Even upon being told how to improve it, my code essentially still doesn't accomplish the task at hand. (currently)

Comment: @Birdman: My concern is the proliferation of code that - unwittingly - sets a bad example. To ask your question here you didn't need to repeat your code: you could have focused on how `.LastUsedTime` doesn't reflect the information you want, and how the AD information doesn't either in that it isn't machine-specific. Your code - which you could have linked to in your original question instead of including it here again - not only doesn't help, it sets a bad example.

Comment: @mklement0 I see. Well I guess I just have to becomes more experienced on SO to understand what you mean. I figured that providing the whole code I'm working with, it would provide context to the problem at hand. I didn't think posting 15 lines of code, even with the focus being one a small portion, would cloud the problem. I could try linking to other questions next time, but my goal in providing the code was for people to see exactly what I was trying to accomplish, and I thought that might provoke thought on how to accomplish it a different way. (that works)

Comment: @Birdman: I appreciate your willingness to have this discussion, and I get that my concerns aren't foremost in your mind while seeking an answer, but I hope that the discussion will provide guidance for the future. The guiding principle when asking a question should be a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The _minimal_ aspect of it means that only as much code as is relevant to the question should be included. Additional code is not only a distraction, but - as in your case - can accidentally exemplify practices that should be avoided.